# Не могу импортировать дизайн с Figma в Android Studio, используя плагин Relay

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, figma

Сегодня пробовал по туториалу перенести дизайн с фигмы на android jetpack compose с помощью плагина Relay. Но когда я вставляю ссылку на элемент и пытаюсь импортировать появляется такая ошибка:

[image: log]